# How to get correct type inference for generic optional function parameters?

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics

Take the following code ([playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBOBbARjMBTAPAMUWwA8pswATAZ0QCVsUAnC3KqRrAcwBpE2OwnAHy8AQkVLlqdBnGat2XXvy5ChACmBw4ALkT5e6AIaMA-HtEBKRAG8AUIkfIEbRI2xQAakYA2iALy2Dk4hAHThWnDcwSGO4aHGjDGIAL52ye5QIIxImd4+dml2KGCuZK6BKBhY2Or2IQjYegDkAPI4zdEpvPVOUADuuojNACqDnYWW6aCQsAiI5VAA0tgAnrgjEmSUNPRMLCqCyoqCapraeiOGJnoA1mtwwIgj1japdosrq+qLvM2NzWsjgA9MDEPkYBQPtg2F8fjCoH8BnBAU5QeDfJDobC1vC2EiABbubCo9EAZQJcBAPgoYGaUEQ6GwiAAbpiKEA)):

```js
function combine<F extends Record<string, string>, B extends Record<string, string>>(foo: F, bar?: B) {
    const retVal = {
        ...foo,
        ...bar
    }

    return retVal
}

const test = combine({
    one: 'One',
}, {
    two: 'Two',
})

function testKey<T extends Record<string, string>>(foo: T, bar: keyof T) { }
testKey(test, 'one')   // Valid
testKey(test, 'two')   // Valid
testKey(test, 'three') // Shouldn't be valid
```

Line 19 shouldn't be valid, but it is. If I hover over `retVal`, the inferred type is this:

```
const retVal: F & {
    [x: string]: string;
}
```

But I'm not sure why it is inferred that way. It is way too permissive. If I change it so that `bar` is NOT optional, then the inferred type of `retVal` is this:

```
const retVal: F & B
```

This is the type inference that I want, but can't figure out a way to get that when `bar` is optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Object.assign` to create the correct intersection type and let `B` default to `{}`:

```
function combine<F extends Record<string, string>, B extends Record<string, string> = {}>(foo: F, bar?: B) {
    const retVal = Object.assign({}, foo, bar);

    return retVal
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBOBbARjMBTAPAMUWwA8pswATAZ0QCVsUAnC3KqRrAcwBpE2OwnAHy8AQkVLlqdBnGat2XXvy5DEAXkQBvAL5CAFMDhwAXIny90AQ0YB+M6ICU2gFCJ3yBG0SNsUAGpWADYaiADy6ABWDFAAdFZUVDCcYPq6vEZwljaOANwubh6+UCCMSMWBQS46BQD0tZ5g3mTemigYWNhpLvUe7gjYZgDkYThD3D0NOrxak32IUADupohDACrL43M6eQUoTVAL2K2eHTjdfQPDo9hbO-ku+1RwQdixQXCc+i1QeYi9y0YAGsaFZDoxwLBUNhEAlEItsEEqi5QJBYAgjmwANLYACeuDWEjIlBo9CYLBUgmUikEQgMmTMa2yjDMQLxcGAiDWzi0iBqPxxuO+xygvCGAyGzncvUqMAoLgFeOFbDFSzgko8vQAcnBDgA3YJyhUiwXK0WrKAAC18t2cvQAypa4CAghQwENDugYQagnKgA)

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't infer correctly when you only pass the first argument. In that case it is inferred as `F & Record<string, string>`. Try calling `combine` like this to see what I mean:

```typescript
const test2 = combine({
    one: 'One'
})

testKey(test2, 'one')   // Valid
testKey(test2, 'two')   // Shouldn't be valid (but it's allowed)
```

Comment: @RyanPalmer Thanks, it looks like you need to add a default type for `B`. I have edited the post, see if it works now [here](https://tsplay.dev/wQ2EJN).

Comment: Great, yes it works now! Between your answer and Robby's, I have two working solutions. Yours is more simple though, so I am making it the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [function overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) to help the compiler along:

```
function combine<F extends Record<string, string>>(foo: F): F;
function combine<F extends Record<string, string>, B extends Record<string, string>>(foo: F, bar: B): F & B;
function combine<F extends Record<string, string>, B extends Record<string, string>>(foo: F, bar?: B) {
    const retVal = {
        ...foo,
        ...bar
    };

    return retVal;
}

const test = combine({
    one: 'One',
}, {
    two: 'Two',
})

function testKey<T extends Record<string, string>>(foo: T, bar: keyof T) { }
testKey(test, 'one')   // Valid
testKey(test, 'two')   // Valid
testKey(test, 'three') // Not valid
```

---

<sup>[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=21&ssc=36&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBOBbARjMBTAPAMUWwA8pswATAZ0QCVsUAnC3KqRrAcwBpE2OwnAHxCAFMDhwAXInwBKGfgDcAKFCRYCZGkw4CRUuWp0GcZq3Zde-LkN4AhA2Uo16TFjcHXLgkeMmKvOgAhowy9gqyiABkiPaq6tDwSCgYWHiEJM7GbmYePjx8BXZxTkaupuaehdV+EtKyQaEA-OFyiADeKog92mBsiIzYUABqwQA2iAC8nd298wB0S-Xcc-M9SwshjGuIAL6qu0NQIIxIx2PjqnsqKij9UIhkAzOputiiXfMI2DIA5AB5HB-VZ7XhfXpQADuDT+ABUYSCVHs5LdEpokM8oABpbAAT1wcLKLhM7gsAhqxTE9RkcKaYUQAGt8XBgIg4e0OvsVFjcXjRFjeH8fn92j0APTixCXGAUHnYNh8gUKqBC6FwUW9SXSiay+WK-HKthqgAWQ2wmu1ADk4I8AG66uVAA)</sup>

Comment: This solution works great. The only reason I chose vr's answer over yours is because it is simpler. But yours might work better for more advanced use cases. Thank you!